# Is there a way to add border on a table of react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using below react component
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table

Is there a way to add a border to this component?

```
const Row = require("react-sticky-table").Row;
<Row style={{ border: 3, bordercolor: "black" }}>
```

is invalid as far as I tried.

Comment: You can create a css file and write your style in it  and then add that class to this component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **borderColor** not **bordercolor**, it should be in camel case and set the **borderWidth** as well

**better method is**

```
<Row style={{border: "3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)"}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The style options you pass in should be in CamelCase, ie. borderColor. You should also probably pass in borderStyle: 'solid' into the style argument.